# How would you extract or slice string like this?

Tags: python, extract, slice

As picture shown, how would you slice or extract 'id' from the 'user' column?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code. Try to create examples as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['id'] = df['user'].apply(lambda x: x['id'])
```

This should work

The column id will contain the ids

Answer (score 1):

The user column looks like JSON. Try `json.loads(df['user'])['id']`.